# Faster copying of math formulas

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, user-interface

I frequently copy math formulas in posts using `Show Math as ▶ TeX commands`. This requires control-click plus mouse movement plus command-A and command-C, a lot of effort. (I'm on a Mac.)

Can this process be simplified, ideally with a single click on the formula?

Comment: BTW, does anyone even copy formulas as Math ML?

Comment: Perhaps not a great improvement, but you can also click on "edit" if you want formula from some post. (The advantage being that you can copy a longer part of the post or several formulas without clicking on each separately.) For comments it might be more complicated, but you can get to source, too: [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234)

Comment: it's a markup language  version. probably easier to copy and paste to a website. if not fancy, just copy and paste the surrounding text sure Mathjax mode is lost, but that's more for fine details, if your browser has certain font capabilities it mostly doesn't matter.

Comment: Here is an older feature request which seems similar to yours: [context menu should allow easy copying of $\TeX$ commands](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6199). (There are also some questions about copying MathJax from posts, such as [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217) and [the posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1217) - although the advice given there is basically what was already said in the above comments and, most likely, stuff that you already know about.)